# how to send a component(containing jsx code) as props to another component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, next.js

I have created a base component(Content.js), and instead of creating duplicates and modifying a small part of it each time in my project, I want to refer my other components to that base file. I want to know if this procedure is correct, and how can I implement this procedure in my project?

in index.js , i want to sent Head component to Content component and show it in Content component.

index :

```
import React , { Component } from "react";
import RightMenu from "../partials/menus/RightMenu";
import Content from "../partials/Content";
import Head from "../partials/contents/head";
import { Card , Container , Row ,  ListGroup , Table , Col } from "react-bootstrap";
import withRedux from "next-redux-wrapper";
import { initStore } from "../../redux/store";
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { PRODUCTS } from "../partials/consts/actionsConstants";
import { products, dispachActions } from "../../redux/actions";
import ProductsItem from "../partials/contents/ProductsItem";
import $ from "jquery";


class Index extends Component {


  render(){

    return(
      <React.Fragment>
        <Container>
          <Row>
            <RightMenu />
            <Content title="storage" k={Head} />
          </Row>
        </Container>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}

export default Index;
```

Head :

```
import React from 'react';

export default function Head() {
    return (
        <div id="storage">
            <Table striped bordered hover>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>id</th>
                        <th>category</th>
                        <th>name</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {productRow}
                </tbody>
            </Table>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Content :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Col, Card } from 'react-bootstrap';

class Content extends Component {
    render() {
        let {title, k} = this.props;
        console.log(k);
        return (
            <Col sm={9} className="text-right">
                <Card >
                    <Card.Header>{title}</Card.Header>
                    <Card.Body>
                        {k}
                        <h1>kkk</h1>
                    </Card.Body >
                </Card>
            </Col>
        )
    }
}
export default Content;
```

Comment: why don't you import that component right inside Content.js file and use it where you want?

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz because as OP said it won't always be just one component

Comment: @awarrier99 Where did he write that? I could not see such requirement

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz "I want to refer my other components to that base file"

Comment: because i use different Component in Content.js... @Zohaib Ijaz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most commonly done using the `children` prop, and rendering components inside of others, like this:

```
class Index extends Component {


  render(){

    return(
      <React.Fragment>
        <Container>
          <Row>
            <RightMenu />
            <Content title="storage">
                <Head />
            </Content>
          </Row>
        </Container>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

```
class Content extends Component {
    render() {
        let {title, children} = this.props;
        console.log(children);
        return (
            <Col sm={9} className="text-right">
                <Card >
                    <Card.Header>{title}</Card.Header>
                    <Card.Body>
                        {children}
                        <h1>kkk</h1>
                    </Card.Body >
                </Card>
            </Col>
        )
    }
}
```

Then you can still pass whichever component you want to your `Content` component and it will render accordingly